# What kind of returns can I expect from a REIT? How can I find a list of legit REITs - especially outside the USA?

Tags: reit

How much money can I expect each month from joining a REIT (I realize it would depend on my investment, let's say I invested $1,000) and where can I find a list of good, safe, legitimate REITs preferably in Europe?

Answer (score 1):

Research Affiliates expects a 10-year real return of about 1.3% on REITs.  See [the graph](http://www.ritholtz.com/blog/2014/10/asset-classes-real-10-year-expected-return/) on Barry Ritholtz's blog.  Here's a screenshot from the [Research Affiliates website](http://www.researchaffiliates.com/AssetAllocation/Pages/Core-Overview.aspx) that shows how they calculated this expected return:

[image: Expected return of REITs]

Comment: For what it's worth, a Real Estate Equity fund accounts for only 5% of my investments, and is there for diversification. In fact it has been doing surprisingly well over the past three years, comparable to the rest of the market -- but I believe it includes more investments in real estate _companies_ than in property per se, so it may be atypical. (Certainly the past five years have been atypical for the US housing market!) Past results are no guarantee etcetera, and I can't claim to have picked this fund on any basis beyond "it was well-rated and convenient."

Answer (score 0):

Returns: Variable, as with all investments.

Legitimate: Contact the usual major investment-fund houses.